# Execute Permissions for "NT Authority\Authenticated Users"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to give `NT Authority\Authenticated Users` Execute permissions on a specific stored procedure? We need ALL SALES associates to be able to access a result set.

We have already tried adding all the users to a group but sql server is not allowing the grant permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.yourprocedurename TO username;
```

Comment: Are you saying I need to grant execute for each user? What if I have 2000 users? Is there a way to provide ALL of them access?

Comment: @CharlesKSQL:- You can use it as `public` like this: `GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.yourprocedurename TO PUBLIC;`